# I want to change image 1 to image 2 if it's clicked then return to image 1 automatically after 1 second

Tags: javascript, if-statement, onclick

When the image is clicked, I want it to change to another image and get pushed to the top

After it's clicked and image 2 appears it returns back to image 1 and get pushed back to the bottom

this is my code so far

```js
function marioAnimation() {
  var i = true;
  var image = document.getElementById("mario1");
  if (i) {
    document.getElementById("mario1").src = "/mario2.png";
    image.style.marginTop = '10px';
    var x = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mario1").src = "/mario1.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="/mario1.png" alt="" id="mario1" onclick="marioAnimation()" style="margin-top: 50px;">

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: 1. What does "pushed to the top" mean and 2. Use setTimeout to defer the change

Comment: [Many,many more examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+image+click+and+back+setTimeout+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: it an animated jump so when you click it add margin top: 15 px so it looks like its jumping, and thank you i'll use setTimeout